# Ember.js createRecord possibly not firing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, local-storage, ember-data

I have an application that saves a user's search criteria in localStorage, where each saved search is represented as an instance of an Ember.js model:

```
Checklist.SavedSearch = DS.Model.extend({
  id: DS.attr('string'),
  filters: DS.attr('string')
});
```

When the "save" button is pressed, the controller creates a model instanced and creates a record for it:

```
Checklist.savedSearchController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  [..]

  save: function(view) {
    var saved_seach = Checklist.SavedSearch.createRecord({
      id: 'abcd',
      filters: '<json>'
    });
    Checklist.local_store.commit();
  }
});
```

`Checklist.local_store` is an adapter I created (this is unsurprisingly where the problem probably begins) that has a basic interface that maps `createRecord`, `updateRecord`, etc. to a bunch of get/set methods that work with localStorage (loosely based on [a github fork of ember-data](https://github.com/thomasboyt/data)). The adapter appears to work fine for some basic tests, particularly as `findAll` has no issues and returns values added manually to localStorage.

Here is the relevant method within `Checklist.local_store`:

```
createRecord: function(store, type, model) {
  model.set('id', this.storage.generateId);

  var item = model.toJSON({associations: true});

  this.storage.setById(this.storage_method, type, id, item);
  store.didCreateRecord(model, item);
}
```

The problem is that when `createRecord` is called by the controller, absolutely nothing occurs. Running it through the debugger, and logging to console, seems to show that the method isn't called at all. I imagine this is a misunderstanding on my part as to how Ember.js is supposed to work. I'd appreciate help on why this is happening.

I come from a ruby and php background, and have perhaps foolishly dived straight in to a JS framework, so any other comments on code style, structure and anything in general are welcome.

Comment: As it turns out, I was doing it wrong. The sample application I was reading from was called `createRecord(<model object>)` however trying some experiments in the console, I have to pass in the model itself: `createRecord(<model>, <model object>)`.

Answer (score 0):

Ember Data doesn't change `createRecord` on the controller so it shouldn't behave any differently. It's possible that there was something related to this in the past, but it's certainly not the case anymore.